# Laravel FFMpeg - FFMpeg cannot edit existing files in-place

Tags: laravel, video, ffmpeg

After I wanted to upload a video in the queue was returned a failed job.

```
 [2020-09-25 13:24:25][125] Processing: App\Jobs\ConvertVideoForStreaming <br /> [2020-09-25 13:24:26][125] Failed:     App\Jobs\ConvertVideoForStreaming
```

So I've took from the DB failed_jobs table the response and run the following:

```
  C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -i "C:\wamp64\www\laravel-stream\storage\app/public\WF3UL8fJTSE7BMxa.mp4" -threads 12 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libmp3lame -b:v 500k -refs 6 -coder 1 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -me_range 16 -subq 7 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -trellis 1 -b:a 128k -vf "[in]scale=720:360 [out]" -pass 1 -passlogfile "C:\Users\wlask\AppData\Local\Temp\ffmpeg-passes5f6dd36a4519fd1fev/pass-5f6dd36a452c9" "C:\wamp64\www\laravel-stream\storage\app/public\WF3UL8fJTSE7BMxa.mp4"
```

Which returned the following:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200726
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\wamp64\www\laravel-stream\storage\app/public\WF3UL8fJTSE7BMxa.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2015-08-07T09:13:02.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:30.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x270 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 301 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-08-07T09:13:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 112 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-08-07T09:13:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
```

> **Output C:\wamp64\www\laravel-stream\storage\app/public\WF3UL8fJTSE7BMxa.mp4 same as Input #0 - exiting**
>
> **FFmpeg cannot edit existing files in-place.**

This was returned after i've run the command from DB failed jobs table return.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg cannot edit videos whose input and output are in the same folder.
You have to configure your video output in other folder.

Comment: No, it's not about the same folder. FFmpeg cannot edit the input file - output has to be a new file.

Comment: @Gyan where should I put the new folder for output? I've tried in storage, storage/app, storage/app/public, public/, public/storage
And in failed jobs it says:
**InvalidArgumentException: Disk [converted_videos] does not have a configured driver.**

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

In the config.filesystems.php I've added

```
        'videos' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/converted_videos'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

And after run, and voilá!

> php artisan config:clear